# Can we fetch all users and session from google analytics using Reporting API in PHP

Tags: php, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I want to fetch all users, session and other tables data from google analytic account.

I check the GA Reporting API, But it provides value in statistics format like total user, session count etc.

Is there any way to fetch the GA data in list format like.

- List of all users including all fields.
- List of all session including all fields.
- Data from all the table available in [this link](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets)

I also check the [GA DEV TOOL](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/), but it provides only counts, not the details.

Comment: sounds like you want to get very detailed information about specific sessions.  And Google Analytics doesn't really provide that.  They do this to prevent you from getting any Personally Identifiable Information.  Most of the data/reports are aggregated.  If you can't get the query in the Query Explorer, then you won't be able to get it using the API (AFAIK query explorer uses API).

Answer (score 0):

The [Google Analytics Core reporting API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference) gives you a wide range of [dimensions and metrics](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets) that you can select out of your Google analytics account.

The format of requests is

```
Authorization: Bearer {oauth2-token}

GET https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/ga
  ?ids=ga:12345
  &start-date=2008-10-01
  &end-date=2008-10-31
  &metrics=ga:sessions,ga:bounces
```

There are some limitations that you should be aware of. You are limited to 7 dimensions and 12 metrics per request.  You are limited to 10000 requests per day pre profile.

An alternative would be to get a [Premium Google analytics](https://www.google.dk/analytics/premium/capabilities.html) account where Google will help you extract your data into bigquery making analysis easer.

As to what format you extract it in that is up to you the API returns the data as JSon, you will have to format it into your list.

Comment: Reason for a -1 on a question that is seven years old?  Care to comment?